# Slow query when grouping by function of a date column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a fairly large table (around 80m rows) containing aggregated pricing data of the lowest price for a particular vehicle based on a particular finance profile i.e. deposit, contract term and allowed annual mileage. The lowest price is aggregated daily.

I want to create two more tables; weekly and monthly aggregations taken from this table, updating daily.
This is the create table statement for the main table.

```
CREATE TABLE `offers_lowest` (
  `cap_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `lowest_price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deposit` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `term` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `mileage` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finance_type` enum('P','B') DEFAULT NULL,
  `offer_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `broker_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_lowest_price` (`lowest_price`),
  KEY `idx_specials_extra` (`finance_type`,`date`),
  KEY `idx_specials_id_price` (`offer_id`,`lowest_price`),
  KEY `idx_price_history` (`cap_id`,`deposit`,`term`,`mileage`,`finance_type`,`date`,`offer_id`,`broker_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I've created a table for weekly aggregation. This is the query I want to use in the INSERT INTO statement:

```
SELECT
    cap_id,
    DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL(-WEEKDAY(date)) DAY),
    MIN(lowest_price) as lowest_price,
    deposit,
    term,
    mileage,
    finance_type,
    offer_id,
    broker_id
FROM
    offers_lowest
GROUP BY cap_id , deposit , term , mileage , finance_type , DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL(-WEEKDAY(date)) DAY) , offer_id , broker_id
```

The query runs in ~50ms without the date function, but runs for minutes with it (I haven't left it long enough to find out exactly how much slower it is).

I think my indexing is correct, unless you can index on a function of a column? I've read around on this but can't figure it out.

Should I create a new column in the main table and fill it with the week commencing date of each date value and then create a new index? If so, what's the best way to do this? I've tried:

```
ALTER TABLE offers_lowest
ADD COLUMN week_start;
UPDATE TABLE offers_lowest (week_start)
SET week_start = DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL(-WEEKDAY(date)) day)
```

to no avail.

EDIT: Ideally the week will be displayed as a date (DD/MM/YYY) and the month as the full month name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main performance problem is caused by rebuilding the summary table again and again, instead of doing it incrementally.

How many rows in the table?  How many days in the dataset?  (I'm wondering how much shrinkage the summary table gives you.)

Consider creating a row for each day, then derive weekly and monthly (and any other date range) from that.  Note that the MIN for a week is the MIN of the 7 daily values.

A minor simplification:

```
DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL(-WEEKDAY(date)) DAY),
```

-->

```
date - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(date) DAY
```

In reference to your first `SELECT ... GROUP BY`, once you have the summary table built, you don't need to rebuild it.  That is, only do `INSERT .. SELECT` with the latest unit of time.  Instead of having the date expression in the  `GROUP BY`,

```
 WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND date  < CURDATE()
```

(That covers "yesterday".)  That will solve the main performance problem; the rest of my points are other tips.

> displayed as a date (DD/MM/YYY)

Use `DATE_FORMAT()` to achieve that format, but *store* dates as "YYYY-MM-DD" so that arithmetic can be performed.

Comment: So there are around 80 million rows in the table, and it's been recording daily since the start of April, so near to 60 unique dates in the date column. To clarify are you saying I should run individual queries for each week, and specify the dates using WHERE rather than trying to get a full list by 'week_start'?

Comment: @AlexMidmore - Yes, the `WHERE` would specify a range of 7 days (or 30, etc).  But you will have a lot more than 60 rows in the summary table -- this table has a `PRIMARY KEY(a, b, date)`, where `a` and `b` are the other column(s) in what you have in your current `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @AlexMidmore - But I have having trouble understanding why `mileage` is in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks, and the mileage is offered in set annual amounts e.g. 5k, 8k, 10k etc and so there will be individual offers for each mileage band

Comment: by the way I'm still struggling with the group by - when I group it by week it times out, is there anything I can do here?

Comment: More on the incremental construction of a summary table:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by week, then just grab the week; something like:

```
SELECT cap_id, datepart(week, date) CalendarWeek, datepart(year, date) CalendarYear
, min(lowest_price) lowest_price ...
GROUP BY cap_id, datepart(week, date), date(year, date), ...
```

Note that you may want to run a SET DATEFIRST x to set the first day of the week (1=Monday, 2=Tuesday, ..., 7=Sunday)

EDIT:  The above query is in SQL Server syntax; the MySQL syntax would be:

```
SELECT cap_id, week(date) CalendarWeek, year(date) CalendarYear
, min(lowest_price) lowest_price ...
GROUP BY cap_id, week(date), year(date), ...
```

Comment: This sounds perfect! Does it affect the query if I don't select CalendarYear? Would the syntax be SET DATEFIRST 1? Thanks!
Edit: the datepart() function doesn't seem to work - is that a MySQL 8.0 feature? I'm on 5.7.12

Comment: Sorry, I gave you SQL Server syntax.  MySQL would be WEEK(date) and YEAR(date).  Also, the week start would be included in the WEEK call [WEEK(date, mode)], but it is less flexible than in SQL Server.  I included Year to disambiguate the dates; if you don't have it, then week 1 of 2021 would be aggregated with week 1 of 2020, for example.

Comment: I'm running this query:
`SELECT 
    cap_id,
    WEEK(date, 1) CalendarWeek,
    YEAR(date) CalendarYear,
    MIN(lowest_price) lowest_price,
    deposit,
    term,
    mileage,
    finance_type,
    offer_id,
    broker_id
FROM
    offers_lowest
GROUP BY cap_id , deposit , term , mileage , finance_type , WEEK(date, 1) , YEAR(date) , offer_id , broker_id`
but it's still timing out after 180 seconds. EXPLAIN shows it's not using the original index (idx_price_history), so it's scanning all 80m rows.

Comment: Will there be an issue with the last (partial) week in one year and the first week of the next?

Comment: You'll need an index on DATE

Comment: @RickJames I thought that - that's why I wanted the week to be set out as a date, so that a week commencing 2021-12-27 and ending on 2021-01-02 would show only as one week, then the next being 2022-01-03 would start again as normal. That's what the DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL(-WEEKDAY(date)) DAY) function was for.